# Failing to update my Routing network Application

Tags: arcgis-server, network-analyst, arccatalog

I am working on the 10.7.1 environment and trying to update my Routing network feature dataset. When I copy the new feature classes and the network dataset to the feature dataset it says " One or more objects failed to paste. The application is not licensed to perform this action" I am on advanced license though. I am doing this using arccatalog. Even when I Import I get an error. I am copying this data from a file geodatabase to an sde db. Any Idea on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works:

- Right-click the feature class
- Open the Index tab
- Select the Attribute Index and Delete it